# How xml Namespaces work?

Tags: xsd, xml-validation

Suppose I have an xml doc which has an attached xsd file. Now suppose the xsd file imports several xsd from different namespaces. When the main XML doc is being validated, does the validation process include a nested loading of all the imported namespaces to perform the validation?

Comment: How do you think it would validate if it didn't?

Comment: so, it does load all xsd docs for the validation process

Answer (score 0):

The validating process needs some way of ensuring that the data defined in your xml document are valid against the types defined in the schema files.

Therefore it must load all the schema files in before it can validate the file. If it can't resolve a schema type which is used in the xml then the validation cannot really pass.

However, there's no standard way for a validator to fail a xml doc for validation, so what happens if your xml is not valid is down to the implementation of the validator.